# Definition of a solution curve in the context of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have always wondered about the precise terminology when it comes down to differential equations. When one talks about a solution curve does this imply that the curve is a function that is well defined (in terms of each $x$ having a maximum of one value of $y$ to map to)?

For example, if we have the differential equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx}2y=1$$ the solution is
$y^2=x+c$. Are the solution curves (three branches?) that are $y=\sqrt (x+c)$  and $y=-\sqrt(x+c)$   for $x>-c$ corresponding to different initial conditions ?

Thank you in advane.

Comment: A curve is in general a geometric object that is the image of a path. Additional to the continuity of the path, often rectifiability, that is, finite length for any bounded segment, is also demanded for a curve. Such a curve could then additionally be a solution of a differential equation.

Answer (score 0):

When a differential equation is solved, the solution will have a constant C.
For example, the solution can be y = x^2 + C.

Each value of C will yield a different a curve. Each such curve is called a solution curve.